# Zend studio with wampserver?

Tags: php, apache, zend-studio, wampserver

Does anyone how I can use my already installed **wamp server** with my **zend studio**.
Do I have to make some kind of configuration for the studio to run on the **wamp server**?
Do I have to save my projects in some specific directory?

I'm totally new in *php* so pleas don't assume anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you want, is when you create a new Zend Studio project, you set its location to a directory under wamp www dir, so, if your wamp www dir is "c:/wamp/www", you create a project on "c:/wamp/www/ProjectName" then you can access it using http://localhost/ProjectName.

As for IDE, I highly suggest you try PhpStorm, it's the best php IDE out there (my opinion). I have tried PhpEdit, Komodo, NetBeans with Php plugin, Eclipse with PDT, used Zend Studio for years(I used from 5.5 to 8).

For using Zend Framework, the best approach is add it to the default wamp include_path, so you don't need to include ZF into each project code. Also, you can setup debugging using xdebug, wamp has support to it.

Comment: The way you suggest I tried to before, and you are right it works. I just thought it was some other alternative more official way of doing it. I'll give it a try for phpStorm. In that way I need to install the zend framework then right; if i need to do work with zend?

Comment: @JhonnyEverson Zend Studio 10 is released do you still hold in favor of PHPStorm? :)

Comment: @LoneWOLFs didn't even see the release notes or tried it, but I would still bet it is better.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove wamp and install Zend Server CE with Zend Studio since they're designed to work together. Alternately, you can use eclipse instead of Zend studio, it's based off eclipse. I've had better performance with eclipse but if your doing a lot of Zend Framework developing Zend Studio should be slightly more efficient.

My experience on Studio version 6.5 was that it was so bloated down and slow that I was actually quicker on eclipse, despite the additional features studio includes. Hopefully, they've fixed it by now.

Your IDE is your primary tool and it's important to use what your most efficient with. And that will change based on the requirements of what your doing. When your learning it's OK to use simpler editors, like notepad. I used vi and pico to learn Java.

You might find it easier to learn the basics in a simple text editor, like jEdit or notepad++. Then move into the production level IDE's and frameworks once you have the basics down.

Comment: I like eclipse and I know it a bit. How do I develop php in eclipse, do I need to install Eclipse web tools, I already have the eclipse for java EE.